# Regex Query -- Grafana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, group-by, grafana

Hi everyone I have `Grafana v 7.5.7` and I'm trying to extract some content from my data.

In this case, my goal is to take the message from snort alert.
I created an event. original as my own variable to collect data from elastic search and now I can see my logs.

**Details from Variables Settings**

```yaml
General

  Name: snort
  Type: Query

Query Options
  
  Data source: Elasticsearch
  Query: {"find": "terms", "field": "event.sms"}
  Regex: /([a-zA-z\a].*)*/


Preview of values

INDICATOR-SCAN SSH brute force login attempt
```

event.sms -> It's the field who stores all my snort's logs

These values are store by a variable called snort.

However, I need to extract only the message of the alert, in the section Query

**Details from Section Query**

````yaml
Query: $snort

Metric(1): Count

Group By -> Terms -> event.sms -> Top 10, Order by: Term value

Then By -> Date Histogram -> @timestamp -> Interval: auto


Preview of values:

05/27-11:30:12.466603 [] [1:19559:13] “INDICATOR-SCAN SSH brute force login attempt” [] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} x.x.x.x:53962 → x.x.x.x:xx```
````

**In Summary**

What I have:

`05/27-11:30:12.466603 [] [1:19559:13] “INDICATOR-SCAN SSH brute force login attempt” [] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} x.x.x.x:53962 → x.x.x.x:xx`

What I need:

INDICATOR-SCAN SSH brute force login attempt

Comment: If anyone can help me I'll be grateful!

Comment: I just saw it, that's much better. As a  general rule, screenshots of text are unhelpful and should be avoided, unless you're specifically talking about a text layout issue.

Comment: Can you help me with my issue?

Comment: I can give you a regex that extracts the part between `“` and `”` from your input string, if that helps.

Comment: OK, but I already have a custom regex in my variable called snort. 
My regex works from my variable section but it doesn't when I try to query it from Grafana's query section.

Comment: The regex you show here (`/([a-zA-z\a].*)*/`) doesn't work, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right and what will be your custom regex?

Comment: Pretty much like the answer you already got, but with typographic quotes instead of straight quotes. `“.*?”`.

Comment: Thanks! the regex you gave me it works from my variable's section   however It doesn't appear from my query's section.                              I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the easiest way to get what's between the quotes:

```
"(.*?)"
```